# how to open file or folder on linux using html?

Tags: linux, hyperlink, xampp

I want to open file or folder  via firefox in linux, 
here the code `<a href="file://///127.0.0.1/media/unknown/Installer/INSTALLER SOFTWARE/LINUX/Application/"> localhost </a>` but it doesnt happen anything. I use xampp and wordpress CMS. how to do that?

Comment: You do it wrong: don't write "127.0.0.1", just start from root directory or current directory.

Comment: iwrite here, but it doen't work `file://////media/unknown/Installer/INSTALLER SOFTWARE/LINUX/Application/`

Comment: `file:///media/unknown/Installer/INSTALLER%20SOFTWARE/LINUX/Application/`

Comment: it's not work too,, i want to open folder like right click 'open containing folder' in firefox download menu..

Comment: I don't know, why you can't do it right, but, for example, `file:///tmp` opens in firefox window directory `\tmp`. BTW, your way is fully incorrect: media could be mounted into any directory; also, you can't simply manipulate with files from browser.